# What is a topological Dirac semimetal?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, topological-insulators

I have just started learning about a topological Dirac semimetal. Then I'm wondering that the Dirac point always crosses the Fermi energy in a topological Dirac semimetal. If the Dirac point does not cross the Fermi energy, does the band structure indicate that the material is not a Dirac semimetal? And I want to know more information about it.